# Why ImageView not Displaying in Activity Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I'm using constraintlayout and I have an activity that is a user profile. and it includes a picture of user. when I code xml layout. I can see the picture in preview window inside android studio the image is a png image. I have tried changing the image to one of the android studio avatar. still doesn't work. however, when I run the app the picture is not displaying. does anyone know why this happen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/profileBackground">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bacround_gradient"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.001">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="Amanda Bozquet"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/headerTextColor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_imageview"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/prifile_pic" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_imageview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.275">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/occupation_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Marine Biologist"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workplace_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Key Biscaine National Park"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/occupation_textview" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/state_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="FL, USA"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/workplace_textview" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/state_textview">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/email_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/state_textview"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mail_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="abozquet@biscainepark.org"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/email_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/state_textview" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phone_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_imageview"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_textview"
                android:layout_width="239dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
                android:text="1 (786) 352-2254"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_textview" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_imageview"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_videocam_white_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_textview"
                android:layout_width="242dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
                android:text="1 (786) 352-2254"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/video_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_textview" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/video_textview"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_facebook" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/facebook_textview"
                android:layout_width="336dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
                android:text="http://facebook.com/amandab"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/facebook_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/video_textview" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/facebook_textview"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_twitter_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_textview"
                android:layout_width="336dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
                android:text="\@mandabuz48"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/twitter_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/facebook_textview" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.

So the attribute:

```
tools:src="@drawable/prifile_pic"
```

is valid only for design-time.
It is not compiled in the APK and you will not see the image when you run the app.
Change it to:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/prifile_pic"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do any of your ImageViews display the intended images? Your profile pic ImageView is using `tools:src` while others are using `app:srcCompat`

I just noticed a potential typo too -

`tools:src="@drawable/prifile_pic"` <<--- supposed to be profile_pic?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exception in your android studio log-cat, like image not found? As **Stitches** wrote in above comment --> typo error for **prifile_pic**, please check you drawable name is same in your xml layout and image name in drawable folder.

Comment: no the name of the picture is prifile_pic.png it is wrong but that is the name. it should work